# Java - Dynamic Web Project - Global Object

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web

Im interesting in Creating a Global Object which will be shared by all my servlets and all my JSP files.
But i dont understand how to do it.
Please advice.

for a senario this object would contain lots of information my servlets and jsp files would like to take information from.
I know how to pass objects between servlets and jsp's.
But i dont know how to initialize 1 global object for the whole "system" or" website"

---

```
<display-name>WebTest1</display-name>
<listener>
    <listener-class>listeners.AppListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>MainPage.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>MainPage.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>MainPage.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SimpleServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.SimpleServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the object inside application context. You can do this when the application starts using [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html).

```
public AppListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //application is being deployed
        //register the "global" object here
        ServletContext sc = sce.getServletContext();
        MyGlobalClass globalObject = ...
        sc.setAttribute("globalObject", globalObject);
    }
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        //application is being undeployed
    }
}
```

Register this class as a listener in web.xml:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>package.where.defined.AppListener</listenerclass>
</listener>
```

Then you can access to this object in both Servlet and JSPs:

Servlet:

```
public void doGet(...) throws ... {
    ServletContext servletContext = request.getServletContext();
    MyGlobalClass globalObject = (MyGlobalClass)servletContext.getAttribute("globalObject");
    //use it...
}
```

JSP:

```
${globalObject.someField}
```

Comment: in this implementation, say i have 10 servlets. how exactly all those servlets know my global object? And when does AppListener runs? When i start my server it runs?

Comment: @user1804659 the listener will be fired automatically when the application is deployed and undeployed. The `ServletContext` is a global object for the whole application. Every servlet may access to ServletContext by using `HttpServletRequest`, you can access to any object in JSP using Expression Language (that thing inside `${}`).

Comment: Now its much CLEARER! Thanks alot mate. I will try this on and see what comes of it!!!

Comment: Luiggi, I want to ask u another question if its ok. If i can access my Object in the JSP file, why would i want to use a servlet? When i can clearly write what ever code i wish in the JSP file ?

Comment: @user1804659 you asked how can you access to this object in Servlets and JSP, and I showed how you can. If you need to access to this global object in one or in others, will entirely depend on your specific functional requirements.

Comment: yes u did. i just wanted to know logically why i would wanna use servlets (for my education) :]

Comment: @Eran for example, you use Hibernate and load a list of countries in `AppListener#contextInitialized` and store them in `Map<Integer, Country> countryMap` (because it is extremely rare a new country appears :) ). Then, you use this map to fill a `<select>` field in JSP for user to select the country he/she belongs. Then, in Servlet, you retrieve the exact `Country` object from this map from `ServletContext` to associate it to the new entity to be persisted in database, there's no need to retrieve the `Country` entity from database since the data won't change too often (or country info does?).

Comment: My great savior Luiggi, when im running my app, it works. but when im adding the    <listener>
  <listener-class>listeners.AppListener</listener-class>
 </listener> to the XML file, it doesnt. its writing HTTP 404, The requested resource is not available. What is wrong?

Comment: @Eran please post how you added the listener in your web.xml file by editing your question.

Comment: @Eran looks like you got an error while creating the object in your listener. Try to wrap the code with a `try-catch` block and print the stacktrace to check which error occurs.

Comment: Again, u are totally right, was a stupid mistake. thanks alot man u are so helpfull!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Eran please don't forget to mark this post as an answer.

Comment: What do u mean? Where do i do that?

Comment: Luiggi, when i try to use my global object as u told me above i do the folloing: ${db.forums.get(1).getName()} but it doesnt work. do i need to do some kind of decleration before? maybe <% %> or somthing like that ?

Comment: @Eran refer to [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197). Also, please refer to [Expression Language](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info).